# Universal app rejected in itunes for "missing screenshot" yet is set for "iPhone" Targeted Device Family

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I upgraded my app to universal, but am not ready yet to release the ipad version just an update to the iphone version, so I set targeted device family to "iPhone". After successful upload of the binary, the app is quickly marked red with "missing screenshot". Presumably, this error is related to a confusion about iPad?  Looking at the ArchiveInfo.plist, the UIDeviceFamily has 2 items in the array (1,2).
What do I need to do to get address this error in itunesconnect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can leave bugs at http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Answer (score 2):

Your targeted device family setting is currently:

```
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1,2
```

It should be:

```
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1
```

Comment: You can find it in the build settings for your target in Xcode.

Comment: I am unable to change the TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY within XCode -- the project is already set to Iphone only. My question was, is there a workaround or something I'm missing. I took dkk's advice and entered a bug at Apple, though they seem to be viewing the issue as user error.

Comment: @user216661: There are several places this value can be set within Xcode; the project level is one, but the target level is another and will override what is set at the project level. What is the value of this key at the target level?

Comment: I recreated the entire project and the problem disappeared.

Comment: How do you recreated the entire project?